# Android Studio (flutter): Unable to start the daemon process

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

I just downloaded android studio, and when I tried to run a flutter project, I got this on the console:

Launching lib\main.dart on Android SDK built for x86 in debug mode...
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Unable to start the daemon process.
  This problem might be caused by incorrect configuration of the daemon.
  For example, an unrecognized jvm option is used.
  Please refer to the User Manual chapter on the daemon at https://docs.gradle.org/6.7/userguide/gradle_daemon.html
  Process command line: C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre1.8.0_301\bin\java.exe -Xmx1536M -Dfile.encoding=windows-1252 -Duser.country=BR -Duser.language=pt -Duser.variant -cp C:\Users\pedro.gradle\wrapper\dists\gradle-6.7-all\cuy9mc7upwgwgeb72wkcrupxe\gradle-6.7\lib\gradle-launcher-6.7.jar org.gradle.launcher.daemon.bootstrap.GradleDaemon 6.7
  Please read the following process output to find out more:

---

Error occurred during initialization of VM
Could not reserve enough space for 1572864KB object heap

- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
  Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1

I tried to delete my ".gradle" file as was recommended in a similar question, but a new ".gradle" file is created in the same folder whenever I try to run the project.